# A method inside a class that calls another method

Tags: python

I need help with the below code. I want to use the `get_skies`, `get_high`, and `get_low` method to call the `set_skies`, `set_high`, and `set_low` methods, respectively, and then return the value for `init_skies`, `init_high`, and `init_low`, respectively.

This is what I have got so far:

```
class WeatherForecast():
  def set_skies(self, init_skies):
     return init_skies

  def set_high(self, init_high):
     return init_high

  def set_low(self, init_low):
     return init_low

  def get_skies(self):
    self.set_skies()

  def get_high(self):
    self.set_high()

  def get_low(self):
    self.set_low()
```

Comment: It's really strange for a `get` method to be `set`ting, unless I'm missing something here

Comment: The get methods are calling the set methods to display its respective value

Comment: Sure... but why? Do you know what getters and setters are? If you're trying to do something different, the terminology is very confusing.

Comment: My apologies, I don't know what Getters and Setters are..would I need to use those to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal is, but why don't you initialize/call the set functions inside `__init__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python attributes of class are publically accessible.
**You don't need to use getter or setters for attributes unless you want to perform some kind of preprocessing or mutation of the attribute**

In your case, you can try this,

```
class WeatherForecast():
    def __init__(self, init_skies, init_low, init_high):
        self._init_skies = init_skies
        self._init_low = init_low
        self._init_high = init_high

    @property
    def skies(self):
        return self._init_skies

    @property
    def high(self):
        return self._init_high

    @property
    def low(self):
        return self._init_low

    @skies.setter
    def skies(self, value):
        self._init_skies = value

    @high.setter
    def high(self, value):
        self._init_high = value

    @low.setter
    def low(self, value):
        self._init_low = value

w = WeatherForecast(1, 2, 3)
print(w.skies, w.low, w.high) # --> print the values

# Set the values
w.skies = 10
w.low = 20
w.high = 30

print(w.skies, w.low, w.high) # -->  print the updated values
```